# Custom SSO with SAML2 and ADFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am looking for Single sign on (SSO) with SAML2 tokens and I have to used ADFS. I can't use WIF.

I googled a lot to understand SSO, SAML2 and ADFS, now I have some doubts which I am not getting.

Scenario: The applications are asp.net MVC application
1. App-A(Windows Authentication) : hosted and it is using ADFS.
2. APP-B(Form Authentication): authenticates the user using the UID and PWD stored in DB.

Do I need a intermediate application to accept the SAML2 token and process it(similar to Identity provider) or it can be done in the App-A itself?

In the App-B what are the things I have to implement to make it aware of SAML2 request(do i need to implement custom handler)?

please help me to choose the right things for the implementation.

--Thanks--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SAML stack for your application.

Refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) and the links in that entry.

For A, perhaps you can use the WIF SAML extension mentioned in the article above?

For B, you need to rip out the DB authentication and add the SAML functionality as for A or else have a look at [Identity Server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2) which you can federate with ADFS and which also authenticates using a DB (but doesn't support SAML itself).

Comment: I would like to add few more inputs and the doubts i am having. We are creating both the application for the application A it is mentioned in the requirement that it should use ADFS using SAML2 token on which some other team is working, I am working on the application B. Do we need an additional server or service to provide the identity? or it can be done by using only these two applications. User will log in to application A and it will request a resource in Application B. what are the things i should implement in App B? please guide. Thanks

Comment: Does the user authenticate on app. B? What is the workflow for "request a resource"?

Comment: User --->App A--->App B. user is logged in the application A using windows authentication(Active Directory is used here) and then user is requesting some resource in the application B which is using form authentication. both application is developed in MVC. I don't have much idea of App A because it is still in the initial phase. but the App B is almost done with its features and now only this part is pending. Now for SSO we have to use ADFS 2.0 in the app A.

Comment: Now what are the things I have to implement in App B. and how I can achieve the SSO for App B. Do i need a custom filter or handler? How the entry point will work here. Do we need any intermediate application to provide the SAML token from App A or it can be done by using ADFS2.0. What are the components I have to write on the APP B side to make it SAML aware? Please guide.

Comment: You need to remove the DB authentication and add WIF in Application B to provide SSO.